# Помогите разобраться в oomph.js

Tags: javascript, html5

Всем привет, недавно узнал про микроформаты hCard и увидел что может быть если подключить файлы jquery.js + oomph.js
Файлы я подключил, а вот эффекта никакого, помогите разобратся в этом, есть у нас какие-нибудь уроки на русском языке где описываются примеры подключения модуля oomph для микроформатов.

Comment: Где увидели? Дали хотя бы ссылку на этот oomph.js

Comment: спасибо уже более менее разобрался, но если так интересно то вот ссылка уже с примером http://prosetech.com/html5/Chapter%2003/Microformats.html